How to import/generate an import library for Embarcadero's RAD Studio 12.1 64-bit modern (clang 15) C++ compiler?
For the older bcc64 64-bit compiler for C++ Builder, mkexp.exe can be used to import a library. Either I am not using it correctly, or mkexp.exe output files are not compatible with the new Win64x (bcc64x) (modern - clang 15) compiler.
How can a .lib be generated from a .dll for the new compiler?
I tried mkexp.exe (the way that works for the old 64-bit compiler). The Embarcadero wiki does not mention anything about generating .lib files for the new target. Or, if it is documented anywhere, I could not find it.

This is addressed in a recent Embarcadero blog post:
How to achieve common tasks with the new Clang toolchain in 12.1

Creating DLL Import Libraries
To import a random DLL, you need an import library. Any existing COFF one should work with our linker (this includes import libraries made by third parties for their DLLs, intended for use with MSVC.)
However, if you need to generate your own, you first need the definition (.def) file for the DLL. To do this, you can use the gendef.exe file from LLVM-MinGW. We aren’t shipping this yet, so you need to download it. Note that the following is third party and not verified or virus-checked by us, but the official llvm-mingw site recommends Martin Storsjö’s github for release. One release is: https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases/tag/20220906
Once you’ve found a copy of gendef.exe, run:
gendef file.dll

This will create file.def.
Note: some people have found that the filename in the .def file is incorrect. A .def file is plain text: you can open it and ensure it contains LIBRARY <dllname>.dll where <dllname> might be wrong: we’ve seen just “a” instead of the actual DLL name.
You can then use our new linker to generate the import library (run this at a RAD Studio Command Prompt, or run rsvars.bat in a normal command prompt):
ld.lld.exe -m i386pep --out-implib file.lib file.def

(Or, using the LLVM tools, use llvm-dlltool.exe.)
And you now have an import library for your DLL: for file.dll, you have a file.lib import library.


I was about to reply to your original comment about it not being a feature yet, but then it disappeared lol. Anyway, thanks! What an oversight on Embarcadero's part for missing this in the 12.1 release as well as 12.1 patch 1.

It is not so much of an oversight. They decided to release the new toolchain sooner rather than later, it just doesn't have all of its features available yet. They are still working on it.


They were able to create libs internally from dlls, which means they had a way to do this (so the feature was already there). 2. Win64x is missing PSDK and other libraries, so, without knowing how to create our own libs, we are stuck. 3. Not sharing the knowledge of how to do this, or including a tool, from day 1, was an oversight, wouldn't you agree? -- All of that said, I am happy with the direction Embarcadero is taking and excited to see what else comes in the future.



They are using the same tools described in the blog. So they are using the same procedure that end users will have to use for now. 2. As the blog says, bcc64x is compatible with MSVC libs, so you should be able to use Microsoft's PSDK libs until Embarcadero ships their own. Embarcadero has simply shipped a command-line compiler and linker, not a fully fleshed out suite yet.

